# Is it possible to bind domain to a specified IP in python?

Tags: python

When I am using python script with some libs(such as `urllib2` or `requests`) to fetch web pages, is it possible to bind a domain to a specified IP in that python env?

I knew I can bind domain to IP in the `hosts` file, but it will affect other processes running on the some machine.

I am finding a way to bind domain to IP just affects in my python script, like this:

```
import requests
bind_domain2IP(DOMAIN, IP)
r = requests.get(DOMAIN)
```

Does anyone have experiences about this? Appreciated for any suggestions.

Comment: you can use a sqlite to bind the values to work only for the your script or use dictonary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's rather advanced.  If you use `requests`, you can configure a [Transport Adapter](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters) for a given domain to control how that http request is handled.

For example, you could create a custom `HTTPAdapter` and override `get_connection()` in your adapter to make a urllib3 connection to the specific IP of your choosing rather than the original domain provided.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

On a simple approach, you could use a dictionary with domain/IP association and connect directly to the IP address with Host HTTP header set to the original hostname>

import requests

```
hosts = {
    'webserver.local': '192.168.1.1'
}

def myreq(hostname, path):
    headers = {}
    if hostname in hosts:
        headers['Host'] = hostname
        hostname = hosts[hostname]
    url = 'http://%s%s' % (hostname, path)
    return requests.get(url, headers=headers)

r = myreq('webserver.local', '/index.html')
```

Comment: Eh, I have thought about this. But what if a link gives 302 redirect contains a domain? There will be no chance to map domain to ip in this way.

Comment: Then you can use this logic inside get_connection() as stated in previous answer.